# Javascript copy text script not working properly?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript for copying text but for some reason it isn't working and i for the life of me can't figure out what!

```
<script>
    function copyText(field) {
        var selectedText = document.selection;
        if (selectedText.type = 'Text') {
            var newRange = selectedText.createRange();
            field.focus();
            field.value = newRange.text;
        } else {
            alert('select a text in the page and then press this button');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note: `document.selection` is deprecated and browsers are starting to no longer support it.  Use `document.getSelection()` or `window.getSelection()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (selectedText.type = 'Text') {
```

should be

```
if (selectedText.type == 'Text') {
```

**=** is for setting

**==** is for comparing

Comment: How is this answer different from the other one?

Comment: @j08691 They're less than a minute apart, it's possible that he was typing when the other one was submitted. Also he explains the difference between `=` and `==` so the OP further understands why the error does what it did.

Comment: SO should show when someone is already answering..

Comment: +1 For explaining the difference between `=` and `==`

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your `if` conditional:

`if (selectedText.type = 'Text')`

should be:

`if (selectedText.type == 'Text')`